# Error when I swap slots using Azure Release Pipeline

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have an Azure App Service to which I can deploy using an Azure Release Pipeline, and it has Deployment slots (to which I can deploy). I want to add a step to my release pipeline to swap between my staging and production slots, using an "Azure App Service Manage" task, but I get an error:

```
Error: Invalid Action selected to use with publish profile endpoint!. Supported actions are
'Start/Stop all continuous webjobs' & 'Install Extensions'
```

I deployed to my staging slot using the "Azure Web App" task, and (for both of these tasks) I specified an Azure Subscription via an Azure Resource Manager service connection.

The documentation for the Azure App Service Manage task says that "Swap Slots" is a valid task (and is the default). https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-app-service-manage?view=azure-devops

I imagine that my publish profile from Visual Studio and the Azure Web App task are the problem, but I don't know how/why. How can I resolve this?

Note that I am using the Web App task, while the deployment task in the "Deploy to Slot" template uses the "Azure App Service Deploy" task instead. But I cannot use that task with an "Azure Resource Manager" connection. (I get a "credentials are null" error.) I'd have to use a Publish Profile connection, but to do that, I'd have to provide a password, but there are no instructions on what this password refers to.

Comment: umm, how about you share your yaml code?

Comment: Hi David, any update on this issue, have your check my answer? does it answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce the same issue on my side:

[image]

The reason is caused by the service connection type in task AzureAppServiceManage@0

This is by design, when the task capture you are using publish profile based authentication and you try to swap, the issue output will return to you.

Solution is using AAD service principal based ARM service connection.

I have done a test and it works fine on my side.

[image]

How to create AAD service principal based service connection:

[Create an Azure Resource Manager service connection with an existing service principal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/connect-to-azure?view=azure-devops#create-an-azure-resource-manager-service-connection-with-an-existing-service-principal)

And

[Give the service principal enough permission](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/quickstart-assign-role-user-portal)

Comment: I wish you could show how you did this with you yml code